# How to design android pop-up window with likely slide list view

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-studio

likely this design ,

pop-up window with likely slide list view
if click arrow button move to next view

please give any ideas with coding...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created likely that.. 
coding & reference here

[view pager reference](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/)

1. pop up window java code

   ```
   public void popUpWindow() {

   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_investment_popup_pageadapter);

   dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.layoutDots1);
   btnPrevious = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
   btnNext = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
   popUpClose = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popUpClose);

   // adding bottom dots
   addBottomDots(0);

   viewPager = (ViewPager) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pager_popUP);
   // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
   adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context, list, ListTotalReturnPrice, population);
   // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
   viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

   dialog.show();

   btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           int current = getSlideItem(+1);
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
       }
   });

   btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // checking for last page
           // if last page home screen will be launched
           int current = getSlideItem(-1);
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
       }
   });

   popUpClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
         dialog.cancel();
       }
   });

   }

   private int getSlideItem(int i) {
   return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
   }

   private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
   dots = new TextView[list.size()];

   int colorsActive = Color.rgb(65, 87, 147);
   int colorsInactive = Color.rgb(217, 217, 217);

   dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
   for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
       dots[i] = new TextView(context);
       dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
       dots[i].setTextSize(35);
       dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive);
       dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
   }

   if (dots.length > 0)
       dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive);
   }
   ```

2.viewpager change listener

```
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        addBottomDots(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
    };
```

3. ViewPagerAdapter class

   ```
       class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
       // Declare Variables
       Context context;
       String[] rank;
       String[] country;
       String[] population;
       LayoutInflater inflater;

       public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list, ArrayList<String> ListTotalReturnPrice, String[] population) {
       this.context = context;
       list = list;
       this.country = country;
       this.population = population;
       this.flag = flag;
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
       return list.size();
       }

       @Override
       public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
       return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
       }

       @Override
       public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

       // Declare Variables
       TextView txtrank;
       TextView txtcountry;
       TextView txtpopulation;

       inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_investment_popup, container, false);

       // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
       txtrank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.popUpMenuTitle2);
       txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView21);
       txtpopulation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView25);

       // Capture position and set to the TextViews
       txtrank.setText(list.get(position));
       txtcountry.setText(ListTotalReturnPrice.get(position));
       // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
       ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

       return itemView;
   }

   @Override
   public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
       // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
       ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);

   }
   }
   ```
4. pop up xml

[image]

5. view pager xml
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Use View Pager indicator  from [**Here.**](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3691) and add two linear layout below it and use it in [**coustom dailog**](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) and Done.

happy coding.

[image]

Comment: hi @Sohail Zahid

i have error with kassis dion ViewPager With Indicator
but i couldn't find that..

Comment: @a.g.thamays what issue you are facing?

Comment: first i checked kassis dion ViewPager With Indicator libeary but that not work

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.agthamays.kassisdion_test/com.example.agthamays.kassisdion_test.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331

Comment: you can use any other view pager query on google `view pager indicator`.and at last if i help you in any way please vote up.